# PHP Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I don't understand this error, perhaps I use in wrong way methods from the extended class.
Something about code: Image class is extending class Database. In Database class I have `selectQuery()` that works fine when I'm using it from Database class, but when I'm trying to call it in construct of Image class I got this error back.

error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\strona\myAPI\Models\Database.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\strona\myAPI\Models\ImageModel.php(26): Database->selectQuery('images', 'imageid = 3333') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\strona\myAPI\Models\ImageModel.php(117): Image->__construct(3333, 3333) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\strona\myAPI\Models\Database.php on line 24

Database.php

```
<?php

class Database
{
    public $con;
    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->con = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . DB_DATABASE_NAME . ';host:' . DB_HOST, "root", "");
            $this->con->exec("set names utf8");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print_r("Something went wrong: <br>" . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function selectQuery(string $where, array $selectors)
    {
        if (isset($where) && isset($selectors)) {
            $selectors = selectorsGen($selectors);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $where  WHERE $selectors ";

            try {
                $stm = $this->con->query($query);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Something went wrong: <br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
            return $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
//rest of database class
```

ImageModel.php

```
<?php

use Image as GlobalImage;

require "./Database.php";

class Image extends Database
{
    public $con;
    public $imageid;
    public function __construct(int $imageid, int $userid)
    {
        $selectors = array(
            "imageid" => $imageid,
            "userid" => $userid,
        );
        $where = "images";
        $data = Database::selectQuery($where, $selectors); //look here
        $this->imagestring = $data['imagestring'];
        $this->imagecomment = $data['imagecomment'];
        $this->imagedate = $data['imagedate'];
        $this->imageprivate = $data['private'];
        $this->imageorder = $data['imageorder'];
        $this->albumid = $data['albumid'];
        }
//rest of image class
}

//this call make this error
$img= new Image(3333, 3333);
echo $img->getImageComment();
```

Comment: `selectQuery()` isn't a static method, you need to create an instance so that `$this` will be set.

Comment: Note: If all you're doing is printing PDOException's message, then you can remove the PDOException try/catch to get the whole stack trace when it fails. You don't need a try/catch to view exceptions, only when you want to handle them beyond printing them.

Comment: Your `Image` class should not extend from `Database`! An image is not a subtype of a database. Use composition.

Comment: There's so much wrong with your `Database` class. Do not use `$this->con->exec("set names utf8");` as this makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection potentially. Also, `utf8` has been deprecated for the past 10 years, use `utf8mb4`. Remove that useless try-catch. It only exposes sensitive information to attackers. Do not use `root` account in your application! What's the purpose of `isset`; clearly the variable is set as it is a mandatory parameter.

Comment: @Dharman How can a hard-coded query make you vulnerable to SQL injection? I've never seen anyone before advocate using a prepared statement for simple queries like that.

Comment: @Barmar Well, it is hardcoded now. But I doubt it will always be hardcoded. Anyway, my comment above meant in general it is possible to cause SQL error due to incorrect character set. It's extremely unlikely to happen and would need exotic circumstances to happen. It's still a bad idea to use `SET NAMES` like this as it's explained in the documentation. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Comment: @Dharman Initialization statements like that are usually hard-coded.

Comment: @Barmar Ohh no. I think you misunderstood me. PDO uses emulated prepares by default. In case, OP would ever want to use prepared statements, and the charset are mismatched, the escaping mechanism in PDO might fail. That is why we never use `SET NAMES` to set the PDO charset. If you disable emulated prepares then it doesn't matter. I didn't mean that `SET NAMES` could be vulnerable to SQL injection in itself.

Comment: Is there ANYTHING common between an image and a database? Is image a database? Really? What makes you think that extending image from a database could possibly be a good idea?

Comment: You should disregard that short-sighted answer below. it doesn't make your code any better

Comment: @Dharman thx, I have removed that exec. Actually it wasn't nesesery :P I'm trying to refresh my PHP coding after 14y break, so that's was use full information for me. Thanks any other advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectQuery()` isn't a static method, it needs to be called through an object. You can use `$this` in the child class.

Also, the child class constructor needs to call the parent class's constructor so that the database connection will be opened.

And then you need to assign the result of `selectQuery()` to the `$data` variable so you can access the columns.

```
class Image extends Database
{
    public $imageid;
    public function __construct(int $imageid, int $userid)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $selectors = array(
            "imageid" => $imageid,
            "userid" => $userid,
        );
        $where = "images";
        $data = $this->selectQuery($where, $selectors); //look here
        $this->imagestring = $data['imagestring'];
        $this->imagecomment = $data['imagecomment'];
        $this->imagedate = $data['imagedate'];
        $this->imageprivate = $data['private'];
        $this->imageorder = $data['imageorder'];
        $this->albumid = $data['albumid'];
    }
//rest of image class
}
```

The child class shouldn't declare its own `$con` variable, it inherits that from the parent automatically.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that this was a child.

Comment: Seems ok now. Fun trivia: `::` and `->` are identical in this context. They are both scope resolution operators. The convention is to use `->` for non-static methods.

Comment: @Dharman Are you saying that `Class::method(...)` is treated a `$this->method(...)` in this context? I didn't know that.